# How to retrieve the value from server side on document.ready in jquery without any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a requirement where i need to retrieve the value from server side code with any event  and use it to make dialogue box.I tried to get the value in window.onload but i got to know that window.onload is called after document.ready function whereas i wanted that value in document.ready function..

My concern is this that is there any way by which i can execute ajax call to get the value from server side and use it without executing any manual event on document.ready function ..

here is my window.onload code..

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Sites',
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {

                var values = [];
                values = data;

                values=values.replace('[','');
                values=values.replace(']','');

                var array = values.split(",");

                for (var i in array){

                    output =output.concat('<input type="checkbox"   id="'+array[i]+'" name="'+array[i]+'" value="'+array[i]+'" />'+array[i]+'<br />');

                }

                console.log(output);
                alert(output);

            }
        });
    });
```

And here is my document.ready function code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //var windowWidth = (document.documentElement.clientWidth - 100) /0.9;
        var chbx="";
        chbx=output.toString();
        alert(chbx);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html("<form id='myform'>" +output + "</form>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Sites',
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            }
        });
```

Here i am trying to access variable **output** i document.raedy function which i need to get from window.load ..but as the problem stated it is coming always empty

Please guys help me..
i am very novice in this field.
thanks in advance//

Comment: which server side technology you are using??

Comment: you can do that but really what you want to do that you can use php to build that page instead.

Comment: Can you put some codes here I think you are making a misunderstanding in somewhere.

Comment: We need to know a few things before we can help you, (1. What is your server side language? (2. What is your Database structure? And (3. What have you already tried? post code here to clarify where it is going wrong. We're here to help when you're stuck, not code for you when you haven't tried anything out yet. What you want is out there on google in many different forms as to how etc. PS: jQuery's `$(document).ready()` - is an event on it's own, so is `$(window).load()`

Comment: @Adi - please check my answer. And let me know if there were any problem. (But you can do this without AJAX just with PHP.)

Comment: PHP is the preffered solution for building your HTML output page, since it's server-side you cannot disable it in the browser. JS should only be used to enhance your website (progressive JS) rather than be dependant on it.

Comment: @Adi - what happend you comment me tons of thanks so why you remove the accept from my answer. Was it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your AJAX call to the server is correct and gives a response (lack of server-side code in OP's question) You should move the ajax call out of the window.load and prepend it before any further functions are executed, this way you can use the generated output by your server to create the page using JS(tho why not do it serverside?)

Anyways - here's an example update of your code, **NOTE** not tested.

```
//Set output variable so that it's accessible for other functions. 
var output = '';
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Do ajax initially.
    //You don't have to wait until the page finished loading all the images.
    //document.ready only loads the DOM, which is needed for this to work.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Sites',
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {

            var values = [];
            values = data;

            values=values.replace('[','');
            values=values.replace(']','');

            var array = values.split(",");

            for (var i in array){

                output =output.concat('<input type="checkbox"   id="'+array[i]+'" name="'+array[i]+'" value="'+array[i]+'" />'+array[i]+'<br />');

            }

            //Do all the further processing on success of the ajax call.
            //var windowWidth = (document.documentElement.clientWidth - 100) /0.9;
            var chbx="";
            chbx=output.toString();
            alert(chbx);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html("<form id='myform'>" +output + "</form>")
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Select Sites',
                buttons: {
                    "Submit": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
                    "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                }
            });

            console.log(output);
            alert(output);

        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT** based on the comments below,

The code that executes after the AJAX should actually be in the `success: function();` callback. I have edited the code above to keep the answer small.

Comment: **Please check my answer.** I think your answer is wrong. Because the 'output' variable will created in AJAX call back that will execute after a short time that ajax call executes. But the codes you have wrote. after $.ajax (`//var windowWidth = (document.documentElement.clientWidth - 100) /0.9;
    var chbx="";
    chbx=output.toString();`) will executes  
 
instantly after $.ajax. so the output variable will still be empty.

Comment: @Adi - what happend you comment me tons of thanks so why you remove the accept from my answer. Was it wrong?

Comment: ok so now you code is more similar to mine please check mine.

Comment: @imsiso you are correct. I added my answer accordingly, thanks for the valuable input and for pointing me towards my logical error!

Answer (score 1):

I have put the ajax calling code just before the dialog code and added an option `async:false` in `$.ajax` so that it will wait till the response is received from the server. So, try the below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //call the ajax first
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Sites',
            dataType: "text",
            async:false,//wait till the data is received from the server
            success: function(data) {

                var values = [];
                values = data;

                values=values.replace('[','');
                values=values.replace(']','');

                var array = values.split(",");

                for (var i in array){

                    output =output.concat('<input type="checkbox"   id="'+array[i]+'" name="'+array[i]+'" value="'+array[i]+'" />'+array[i]+'<br />');

                }

                console.log(output);
                alert(output);

            }
        });

        ///then here comes you code for dialog

        var chbx="";
        chbx=output.toString();
        alert(chbx);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html("<form id='myform'>" +output + "</form>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Sites',
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that now this would wait ajax complete and then runs the remaining? if Yes I should put +1 to you. Would you mind give some references on this?

Comment: Yes, adding async:false will wait till the data is fetch from the server, for more reference see this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: But I'm going to take it back You know why? Cause my answer is more correct than yours. ( no  I'm not doing that (-:)

Comment: please check the link you gave me.  This is in your link and it says that your solution is not recommended. `By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this ` ....

Comment: .... `option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().`

Comment: But I don't think you should face any problem in implementing this !

Comment: I know and that why you still have the +1. (-: